# Aspect-ratio-dependent configuration

Tags: vimrc

I'm currently using [ALE](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale) and pretty much enjoying it. By default, it puts its loc-list at the bottom of the screen. This is great on a vertical monitor, but when I'm using my laptop, I want it to be at the right of my screen. Is it possible to get the screen dimensions in vimrc, so that I can move the list to the right when I'm not using a vertical monitor?

Comment: Screen dimensions? Isn't Vim's window height applicable here? You can get that for the current window with `winheight(0)` (test with `:echo winheight(0)`).

Comment: I usually avoid opening the location or quickfix lists when i dont need to, fwiw. I just navigate between errors.